# My Rockshox fork won't close

Tags: fork

I have a Diamondback Apex with Rockshox xc30 and all I did was turn the knob for the preload adjustment and it suddenly came off. I tried putting it back together but it won't go all the way back in. I try riding it but even the lockout won't hold the crown from slipping all the way down. This makes the hole spring be seen and the handlebars very low. The suspension is now rough and useless.
What should I do?

Comment: If you are not comfortable with overhauling or disassembling and reassembling the fork then take it to your local bike shop.

Comment: Being blunt **stop riding on it** else you may create more damage, the sort that can't be fixed.  I know that I know nothing about suspension, so I'd take it into my LBS for paid help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably broken something in the fork. Bring back to the shop to have it check!